# How to find not-crossing time sets using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have N records in table T. Each has time interval - startTime, endTime in unix timestamp format. I want to generate a list of time intervals (start+end times) from lowest startTime to Now, where no record had time interval at that time. How to do such thing with MySQL?

Having data like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13fddf/9)
we would like to get values

```
(3, 4)
(9, 10)
(13, NOW())
```

Comment: Just want to know, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, the maximum number of "gaps" is equal to the number of time intervals you have.

With that in mind here is my attempt at your problem :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  gaps.gapStartTime as gapStartTime,
  coalesce(gaps.gapEndTime, NOW()) as gapEndTime
FROM
  /* Subquery to get the data we need to "build" the gaps*/
  (SELECT
    e1.endTime as gapStartTime,
    /* There is a gap if the endTime is not between another interval */
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM e AS e2 WHERE
     e1.endTime between e2.startTime and e2.endTime and
     e1.endTime <> e2.endTime and
     e1.id <> e2.id)
    THEN
      "false"
    ELSE "true" END AS isGap,
    (select min(e3.startTime) FROM e as e3 WHERE e3.startTime > e1.endTime) as gapEndTime
  FROM E AS e1) AS gaps
WHERE
  isGap = "true"
ORDER BY 
  gaps.gapStartTime
```

Have a look at the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13fddf/110).

Edit: Forgot the `ORDER BY` clause.